# Can I transfer my Terraria world from one PC to another?

Tags: terraria

I have two Terraria worlds, one on my laptop and the other on my PC. I want to transfer over my laptop world to the PC, whilst keeping the existing PC world.

So I'm looking at my laptop and the files name is *world1.wld* and the game on my PC has the same name. Do I have to rename the file to *world2.wld*?

Comment: Keep in mind that moving world does **NOT** move characters! A character is completely separate. If you want to keep your character too, you'll have to move that too in a similar manner(I don't know right now what the filenames would be). Having multiple characters with the same ingame-name is possible, slightly confusing in the menu though.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if you wish to have both worlds on your PC (assuming that's the destination computer), you need to rename the transferred file to "world2.wld". Otherwise, the older one will be replaced by the newer one.

Comment: You don't have to rename it. Terraria will pick up any *.wld file in the correct folder. (Even one named world2 - Copy.wld) It won't display any more than five in the menu though.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to transfer player files to another PC, the player files are in the a similar area to the world files.  If your world files are in \Terraria\Worlds, then your player files are in \Terraria\Players. (At least they are this way on Vista.)  The files are named like the worlds... Player1.plr, Player2.plr, ect.  Don't forget to back up the files before messing around, for example make a copy of the Players and Worlds directory (or at least the files you want to work with) before copying.