# Moving Terraria Profiles from Mac OSX to PC Windows 10

Tags: steam, terraria

I recently bought a new PC for gaming and I want to transfer my Terraria profiles from my Mac to my PC. I used my profile to log onto my PC my, but my worlds aren't showing up.

How can I migrate my world? Can't I use the Steam Cloud for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I transfer my Terraria world from one PC to another?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126492/can-i-transfer-my-terraria-world-from-one-pc-to-another)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Steam version and 1.3, click the cloud icon on the bottomleft of the player/world card, then go to the other computer and you can access it.